# Programmatically changing the current device profile in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to find an API in the Blackberry JDK that will allow me to change the device's current profile. For example, I'd like to call an API to change it from "Loud" to "Vibrate" or "Quiet" mode; these options are accessible via the Speaker icon on the main blackberry screen.

Is there any way to do this programmatically?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes,  we can do that by launching the phones profile application from within your app with the following. From there you can edit a profile and set the volume.

```
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_profiles_app");
```